# CentOS memory usage. About 22GB of RAM used from 22GB available

Tags: mysql, apache, memory-management, shared

For several months I have a problem with my physical shared hosting server. There is 24Gb of RAM on my dedicated server with 8 cores CPU. I have a problem with memory leaks. Something wrong with setup maybe, or with hardware configuration. I need to find the reason. After rebooting of my server I have about 22Gb of free RAM and then during the day it's all time increases. I'm watching via top, sar, ps other task managers, but I can't find the tasks, which totally eating the memory. Now I have only ~40 Mb of free memory from 24Gb. swap only 512 mb but sar shows me 0.2% of its usage.

```
root@srv [~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24149      23689        459          0       2958      17862
-/+ buffers/cache:       2868      21280
Swap:          513          0        512
```

also **top** results:

```
Mem:  24728844k total, 24463380k used,   265464k free,  3029508k buffers
Swap:   525916k total,      816k used,   525100k free, 18316304k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 6307 someuser  20   0  151m  55m 6068 S 18.0  0.2   0:00.54 php
 6313 someuser  20   0  144m  50m 5908 R 12.3  0.2   0:00.37 php
 6316 someuser  20   0  141m  46m 5700 R  9.3  0.2   0:00.28 php
 6991 mysql     20   0  545m 249m 5740 S  9.0  1.0  24:41.08 mysqld
 6310 someuser  20   0  713m  62m  30m S  7.6  0.3   0:00.23 php
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:07.15 ksoftirqd/6
 5012 nobody    20   0 71220 5580 1868 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.04 httpd
 6036 nobody    20   0 71372 5640 1768 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.01 httpd
 6056 root      20   0 12804 1228  840 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.05 top
```

I know, some applications can use a lot of memory, but where they are? Stopping Apache or MySQL didn't help too. I have another server with 64Gb of RAM. After about a week of its interruptible running and hard using there is about 30Gb available from 64Gb. Why so? How can I calculate the ratio between physical memory \ used buffers etc.? And how it can be decreased? How can I really determine how much resources uses each application? What will be if I install an application which will requires e.g. 6GB of RAM?

Comment: You have only `2868Mb` RAM used (and `< 1Mb` swap) at this moment http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Hi, you see new here. This is an interesting question... but unfortunately it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow - which is more aimed at programming questions. This question is a better fit for SuperUser (http://superuser.com/) - which is all about this kind of thing. I'll flag your question to be moved over there, but that might take some time for our busy mods - if your question is urgent, you might want to go and re-ask your question there

Answer (score 4):

Linux aggressively uses free memory for caches and buffers.  If your applications need that memory, the kernel will gladly hand it over.

Look at the **3rd** line of output from `free -m`, the one labelled `-/+ buffers/cache:` -- that's the most accurate representation of how much memory is "free".

See: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/